# Why cant we download app files in PC

Tags: apps, lumia-520, downloads

I am trying to install an app in my lumia phone because the app size is greater than 100 MB i chose to download it from PC. I usually download and install big file apps of windows phone  using [this method](http://www.versedtech.org/8987/download-and-install-windows-phone-apps/). But now I cant find **Download and install manually** button. I only get a **Get the app** button and it doesn't work when clicked. Any idea how to download windows phone apps file to PC.

Comment: Yes you are right **Get the app** for mobile devices on Windows store is currently disabled `btn btn-default disabled`, so clicking on it wont work unless even desktop version is there where it opens up Desktop store app.

Comment: I'd have to double-check to be sure, but I think Microsoft has disabled this ever since Windows 10 was released.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot download windows mobile apps from a PC.**

The option to download the offline app setup for windows phone has been **disabled by Microsoft** ever since the merger of Windows phone store with the windows store.

Here is a [article from techmesto.com](https://www.techmesto.com/download-windows-phone-apps-to-pc/) whaich says,

> Microsoft has recently merged the Windows Phone and Windows store. The
>   manual download options seems no longer available .................... We
>   will update the post if things change.

Answer (score 1):

although there is no windowsphone.com , we still can download apps from www.appx4fun.com or you could use following steps.

- First go to the store, open an app which you want to enquire.
- Copy the link.
- Next open the link i provided on browser & Paste the Store URL of the  required app and hit submit button.
- Now u can download the file.
- Rename it to ***.appx or ***.xap and copy to sd and install.

LInk: http://winphonehub-apps.appspot.com/

Comment: It does not work for PC-onl or UWP only apps. It works for apps that are in WP8.1. The best part is I could see the last updated date.